# possible to fetch data from firebase inside of a tableView Cell?

Tags: ios, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from firebase and place it inside of a tableViewCell. Very similar to a notifications View controller on Instagram. Where the cell holds a name, picture and description of the notification. I can fetch the data, have it print as a snapshot inside of my console, but if I call userArray.count inside of numberOfRowsInSection the section returns blank. On the contrary, If I were to return a number such as 2 inside of numberOfRowsInSection, I can successfully see the review.

to show with pictures

[image: image 1]

the above image is when

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return 2
}
```

is called but when I call

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return userArray.count
}
```

I get

[image: image 2]

The code I am using to call this information is

```
class UserModal {


       var userImage: String?
       var name: String?
       var review: String?

    init(userImage: String, name: String, review: String) {

        if let fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String {
           self.fromId = fromId
        }

        if let categoryLabel = dictionary["jobName"] as? String {
            self.category = categoryLabel
        }

        if let jobImage = dictionary["jobImage"] as? String {
            self.jobImage = jobImage
        }

    }


}

  var userArray = [UserRecentModal]()

     func fetchRecentsNSetupViews() {

 guard let currentID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
 REVIEW_JOB.child(currentID).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
 guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }

 guard let fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String else { return }
 guard let jobName = dictionary["jobName"] as? String else { return }
 guard let jobImageUrl = dictionary["jobImage"] as? String else { return }
//             self.imageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(jobImageUrl)
   //
//        self.nameLabel.text = fromId
//  

  self.categoryLabel.text = jobName


    Database.fetchUser(with: fromId, completion: { (user) in
        if let postId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String {

            Database.fetchPoster(with: postId, completion: {(poster) in

                let array = UserModal(jobImage: jobImageUrl, fromId: fromId, category: jobName, dictionary: dictionary)
                self.userArr.append(array)

            })

        }
    })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling `fetchRecentsNSetupViews()`? If you're calling it in the `cellForRowAt` method, you'll encounter problems because while the table view is setting up, you won't know when the data from `fetchRecentsNSetupViews()` will populate `userArray.count`. Thus, the table view may know even have the data in time to know it is 2 users. It would be better if you downloaded the data before the table view begins its setup.

Comment: its called     override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        fetchRecentsNSetupViews()
    }

Comment: Try initiating `fetchRecentsNSetupViews()` in `viewDidLoad` so that you can populate `userArray.count`. Once you have retrieved the data, reload the table view in `viewDidLoad` to use the count of `userArray`. Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: I have a tableView inside of a collectionView. I can only fetch the reviews inside of the tableView. Or at least I think I have to.

Comment: Have you tried loading the data as per my recommendation? If it doesn't work, you can elaborate more about your issue and I can try to help.

Comment: I have tried loading inside of ViewDidLoad. Would you like to continue over in private chat??

Comment: Sure. What do you want to use to chat? Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210709/discussion-between-zach-wilcox-and-mat).